# How do I test whether a touchinput in Windows is from a finger or the stylus? in C/C++

Tags: c++, windows, touch

I have a windows multi-touch app where I want to treat touch events from the stylus/pen differently than events from a finger.

I have been searching microsoft docs for hours to see how to determine this.

Is it possible? (I can't believe not)

A secondary thing is how to determine the state of the "pen button" (or buttons) when the pen is touching.

Comment: I recommend searching the data sheets of the touch pad device to see if the touch pad can differentiate between finger and stylus.

Comment: If you are prepared for a bit of tedious work this should be possible using [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx). Unless both input types come from the same hardware device. In that case the only viable solution I could think of is to interpret the touch contact area passed to WM_TOUCH messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well seems the issue is the old pre-windows 8 API doesn't support that information.  You have to use the newer API which is only available on windows 8+ the "Pointer Input" messages and associated structures and methods.

And you have to use the headers and libs from the new SDK.